# VB.NET Find certain text in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`

`TextBox1` has this in it

```
pooy
```

`TextBox2` has this in it

```
dalton austin chicken pooy boddy chicken
```

And when you click on `Button1` it will look for the text "pooy" if it has it, it will go to `Form2` if it doesn't nothing happens.

How can I do this?

EDIT: GOT IT WORKING

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Activiated")
    My.Settings.key = TextBox1.Text
Else
    MsgBox("Invalid Key... ")
End If
```

Comment: Handle the click event of the button. Search the content of the textbox. Branch on your result.

Comment: I dont know how to SEARCH the content of the textbox why do you think i asked this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you asked, as you didn't say. A textbox will have a property which holds its text value -- usually this is a string. Strings have an IndexOf method, which can be used to search the string.

Comment: If TextBox1.Text.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Activiated")
            My.Settings.key = TextBox1.Text
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Key... Buy at kramansro.net/fb")

        End If

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the **.contains** or **.indexof** methods. I believe in your example code you have it backards - it should be this, shouldn't it?

```
TextBox2.Text.Contains(TextBox1.Text)
```

As a side note, Contains is actually just a wrapper method for IndexOf that returns a Boolean. (IndexOf will return -1 if the string is not found).

Inside Contains:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal value As String) As Boolean   
    Return (Me.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
End Function
```

IndexOf is slightly more flexible since you change the case-sensitive option:

```
If myString.IndexOf(mySubstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps you to validate the text values only with string values

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, @"[a-zA-Z]"))
{
    errorProvider2.SetError(textBox3, "Only use alphabets")
}
```